# How to implement a input box with bokeh-server?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I want to implement a simple dashboard prototype with following structure and functionality.

### Step 1

User types into a input box in order to pass parameter to a SQL query.

SQL query looks like:

```
select * 
from table_name
where col1=?
```

? is the parameter coming from the input box

### Step 2

Server connects to backend database and fetch the data with previous SQL query, after that process it

### Step 3

Pass the processed data as data source to a line glyph to be visualized

How can I implement **input box** with bokeh to do interactive visualization?